# Unable to get discount details in shopify from my application

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am writing a shopify application using node platform, I am trying to get discount info in shopify from my application using the npm module "shopify-node-api", it shows "404- Not Found" error, but,  I am able to get products and custom_collections by this method.

```
var Shopify = require('shopify-node-api'); 
var config = {};
config.shop = myshop.myshopify.com;
config.shopify_api_key = XXXX;
config.shopify_shared_secret = XXXX;
config.access_token = XXXX;
sails.log.verbose('Shopify config object: ', config);
var shopify = new Shopify(config);
shopify.get('/admin/discounts.json', function(err, data)
if (err) {
  sails.log.error("Error in getDiscount ", err);
} else {
  sails.log.verbose(" shopify.getDiscount data ", data);
}
```

Also I able to get discount details using the URL `https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/discounts.json` and the output as

```
{
    discounts: [
        {
        id: 4128341132,
        code: "GET4PRODUCT",
        value: "10.00",
        ends_at: null,
        starts_at: "2017-03-09T00:00:00-08:00",
        status: "enabled",
        minimum_order_amount: "0.00",
        usage_limit: null,
        applies_to_id: 9720854796,
        applies_once: true,
        applies_once_per_customer: true,
        discount_type: "fixed_amount",
        applies_to_resource: "product",
        times_used: 0,
        applies_to: {
            id: 9720854796,
            title: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            body_html: "<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
            <ul class="a-vertical a-spacing-none">
            <li><span class="a-list-item">Outer Material: EVA Sheet</span></li>
            <li><span class="a-list-item">Sole Material: Anti Slip EVA Sole</span></li>
            </ul>",
            vendor: "myshop",
            product_type: "",
            created_at: "2017-02-18T05:24:52-08:00",
            handle: "adreno-mens-blue-slippers",
            updated_at: "2017-02-18T05:28:20-08:00",
            published_at: "2017-02-18T05:23:00-08:00",
            template_suffix: null,
            published_scope: "global",
            tags: ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I unable to get discount objects using my application. Do I need to provide any other credentials or is there any other method to get the discount object from my application.

Please help me for getting discount json from an application.

Comment: Discounts API is only for Shopify Plus accounts. Are you working on a Plus account?

Comment: I am not using Shopify Plus account, but I am able to create discount coupons, view those coupons in Shopify store owner url https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/discounts.json and redeem the coupon at checkout. So, my guess is that if i can get those details using my Shopify login credentials, I should be able to get those details from my application as well.

Comment: I have added the discount objects obtained using the URL [link](https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/discounts.json) to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HymnZ is correct, the Discounts endpoint is only API-accessible for Plus store accounts.

If you are not a Plus subscriber, you can access the Discounts endpoint in your browser with an admin-authenticated session, but not using API credentials.